# Ionic 3 — Push page w/o PageName but w/ expression/variable/…?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

### Introduction

**Hi! I’m working with Ionic 3 and trying to create a little web application. Until now everything worked fine, but now I stick in the mud:**

*This is my very first question on StackOverflow after researching the whole web for days, so please keep that in mind… I really tried my best to create an accurate question. :)*

I have a list of items on a page. When you click on one them, a page with details opens. To achieve unique content on each detail page (which in fact is just one page I created) I’m using {{expressions}} to display data from a data.json file. So far, so good.

But now I want to have a button on each detail page, which opens another page. This should not just be another page which stores and shows data, but an individual page, where I could place content as I like.

---

**An example to make it clear:**
I’ve got 5 list items. If you click an item (click)="goToDetailPage(...)" it directs you to the DetailPage which shows content via *ngIf="details" and some {{expressions}}. So at the end just one single html file which shows individual content for the item you clicked.

```
goToDetailPage(detailsData: any) {
this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, {expressions});}
```

- item01 > DetailPage
- item02 > DetailPage
- item03 > DetailPage
- item04 > DetailPage
- item05 > DetailPage

Now I want a button on that DetailPage that directs the user to a unique page, means for item01 > MoreDetailsPage01, for item02 > MoreDetailsPage02, for item03 > MoreDetailsPage03, for item04 > MoreDetailsPage04 and for item05 > MoreDetailsPage05

- item01 > DetailPage > button > MoreDetailsPage01
- item02 > DetailPage > button > MoreDetailsPage02
- item03 > DetailPage > button > MoreDetailsPage03
- item04 > DetailPage > button > MoreDetailsPage04
- item05 > DetailPage > button > MoreDetailsPage05

---

**And this is where I get stuck!**

Of course, the button is not the problem… ;) There’s also no problem for me to direct one page to another. But: In this case I don’t have a normal Ionic page with a button which directs the user to another page (or a ModalPage or just a ViewPage), but a single page (the DetailPage), which has content that only exists due to the data provided from the .json file. I really need a solution how to use some kind of placeholder/variable/expression or whatever to achieve what I’m looking for.

*Really appreciate your help guys and I’m really excited if my first question is going to get answered… :)*

**Thanks!**

*BTW: I hope that the title/my question is correct for that case.*

---

### Code

*Here’s how the things work that work (this is not the code I’m having problems with. The code part I’m having problems doesn’t even exist, cause I have no idea how to handle it. This is just the code requested – and I really hope that makes my issues clear):*

---

This is the ListPage, where the ion-list/ion-item data comes from a .json file. This is the place where you click item01, item02, item03, item04, item05 (of course much more, but this is just the example) to goToDetailPage (this is just the necessary code part of this file). **list.html**

```
<ion-content>
   <ion-list #topicList [hidden]="shownDetails === 0">
   <ion-item-group *ngFor="let group of groups" [hidden]="group.hide">

     <ion-item-divider sticky>
       <ion-label>{{group.topic}}</ion-label>
     </ion-item-divider>

   <ion-item-sliding *ngFor="let detail of group.details" #slidingItem [attr.track]="detail.tracks[0] | lowercase" [hidden]="detail.hide">

    <button ion-item (click)="goToDetailPage(detail)">
      <h3>{{detail.name}}</h3>
      <p>
        {{detail.timeStart}} &mdash;
        {{detail.timeEnd}}:
        {{detail.location}}
      </p>
      <p>{{detail.category}}</p>
    </button>

    <ion-item-options>
      <button ion-button color="secondary" (click)="addFavorite(slidingItem, session)" *ngIf="segment === 'all'">
        Favorite
      </button>
      <button ion-button color="primary" (click)="removeFavorite(slidingItem, session, 'Remove Favorite')" *ngIf="segment === 'favorites'">
        Remove
      </button>
    </ion-item-options>

   </ion-item-sliding>

   </ion-item-group>
   </ion-list>

   <ion-list-header [hidden]="shownDetails > 0">No Sessions Found</ion-list-header>

</ion-content>
```

---

This is the .ts file of ListPage (this is just the necessary code part of this file). Here you’ll find the goToDetailPage function that pushes the DetailPage with its .json provided data: **list.ts**

```
import { Component, ViewChild } from '@angular/core';
import { AlertController, App, FabContainer, ItemSliding, List, ModalController, NavController, ToastController, LoadingController, Refresher } from 'ionic-angular';
import { DetaData } from '../../providers/deta-data';
import { UserData } from '../../providers/user-data';
import { DetailPage } from '../detail/detail';
import { TopicFilterPage } from '../topic-filter/topic-filter';

@Component({
 selector: 'page-list',
 templateUrl: 'list.html',
})

export class ListPage {
@ViewChild('topicList', { read: List }) topicList: List;

dayIndex = 0;
queryText = '';
segment = 'all';
excludeTracks: any = [];
shownDetails: any = [];
groups: any = [];
detailDate: string;

constructor(
  public alertCtrl: AlertController,
  public app: App,
  public loadingCtrl: LoadingController,
  public modalCtrl: ModalController,
  public navCtrl: NavController,
  public toastCtrl: ToastController,
  public detData: DetaData,
  public user: UserData,
) {}

ionViewDidLoad() {
  this.app.setTitle('Topics');
  this.updateTopics();
}

updateTopic() {
  this.topicList && this.topicList.closeSlidingItems();

this.detData.getTimeline(this.dayIndex, this.queryText, this.excludeTracks, this.segment).subscribe((data: any) => {
  this.shownDetails = data.shownDetails;
  this.groups = data.groups;
});

}

presentFilter() {
  let modal = this.modalCtrl.create(TopicFilterPage, this.excludeTracks);
  modal.present();

  modal.onWillDismiss((data: any[]) => {
    if (data) {
      this.excludeTracks = data;
      this.updateTopic();
    }
  });

}

goToDetailPage(detailData: any) {
  this.navCtrl.push(DetailPage, { detailId: detailData.id, name: 
detailData.name });
}

addFavorite(slidingItem: ItemSliding, detailData: any) {

  if (this.user.hasFavorite(detailData.name)) {
    this.removeFavorite(slidingItem, detailData, 'Favorite already added');
  } else {
    this.user.addFavorite(detailData.name);

    let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
      title: 'Favorite Added',
      buttons: [{
        text: 'OK',
        handler: () => {
        slidingItem.close();
        }
      }]
    });
    alert.present();
  }

}

removeFavorite(slidingItem: ItemSliding, detailData: any, title: string) {
let alert = this.alertCtrl.create({
  title: title,
  message: 'Would you like to remove this session from your favorites?',
  buttons: [
    {
      text: 'Cancel',
      handler: () => {
        slidingItem.close();
      }
    },
    {
      text: 'Remove',
      handler: () => {
      this.user.removeFavorite(detailData.name);
        this.updateSchedule();
        slidingItem.close();
      }
    }
  ]
 });
    alert.present();
 }
}
```

---

And here comes the one and only DetailPage, which opens whenever someone clicks an item on my ListPage: **detail.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar>
    <ion-title *ngIf="detail">{{detail.name}}</ion-title>
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
          <ion-card-title *ngIf="detail">{{detail.name}}</ion-card-title>
      <p>The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. 
      </p>
          <button ion-button (click)="openModal()">Open Project</button>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>


    <ion-card>
        <ion-card-content>
           <div *ngIf="detail">
              <h1>{{detail.name}}</h1>
              <p>{{detail.timeStart}} - {{session.timeEnd}}</p>
              <p>{{detail.location}}</p>
              <p>{{detail.description}}</p>
           </div>
        </ion-card-content>
    </ion-card>

</ion-content>
```

---

And here comes the final part – the detail.ts file, which loads all the data for the DetailPage: **detail.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

import { DetaData } from '../../providers/deta-data';

@Component({
  selector: 'page-detail',
  templateUrl: 'detail.html'
})

export class DetailPage {
  detail: any;

constructor(
  public dataProvider: DetaData,
  public navParams: NavParams,
) {}

ionViewWillEnter() {
  this.dataProvider.load().subscribe((data: any) => {
    if (
      data &&
      data.topic &&
      data.topic[0] &&
      data.topic[0].groups
    ) {
      for (const group of data.topic[0].groups) {
        if (group && group.details) {
          for (const detail of group.details) {
            if (detail && detail.id === this.navParams.data.detailId) {
              this.detail = detail;
              break;
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  });
}
}
```

---

To make it complete – the .json file content: **data.json**

```
{

"topics": [{
  "date": "DatePlaceholder",
  "groups": [{
    "topic": "TopicPlaceholder",
    "details": [{
      "name": "NamePlaceholder",
      "location": "LocationPlaceholder",
      "description": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
      "timeStart": "TimeStartPlaceholder",
      "timeEnd": "TimeEndPlaceholder",
    "categorie": "CategoryPlaceholder",
      "tracks": ["TracksPlaceholder"],
      "id": "1"
    }]
  }, {
    "topic": "TopicPlaceholder",
    "details": [{
      "name": "NamePlaceholder",
      "location": "LocationPlaceholder",
      "description": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
      "timeStart": "TimeStartPlaceholder",
      "timeEnd": "TimeEndPlaceholder",
    "categorie": "CategoryPlaceholder",
      "tracks": ["TracksPlaceholder"],
      "id": "2"
    }, {
      "name": "NamePlaceholder",
      "location": "LocationPlaceholder",
      "description": "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog. The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.",
      "timeStart": "TimeStartPlaceholder",
      "timeEnd": "TimeEndPlaceholder",
    "categorie": "CategoryPlaceholder",
      "tracks": ["TracksPlaceholder"],
      "id": "3"
    }, {
    }]
  },

    and so on…
}
```

---

I want to open a modal (or maybe just another blank page) after clicking the button, which you can see as part of detail.html above. I know how to do things like that:

**.html file:**

```
<button ion-button (click)="openModal()">Open Modal</button>
```

**.ts file:**

```
export class SomePage {

  constructor(
  public navCtrl: NavController, 
  public modalCtrl : ModalController
) {}

  public openModal(){ var modalPage = this.modalCtrl.create('ModalPage'); modalPage.present(); }

}
```

But this is a hard coded blank ModalPage. And if I would use this for detail.html it would always open the same ModalPage (with the same content) for every single item.

But I don’t want to fill the ModalPage with content that comes from (.json) data.

I want to create one ModalPage01.html (modal page or classic page, that doesn’t really matter, but I use the modal page for this example) for item01 that opens after you click the button on DetailPage (detail.html), one ModalPage02.html for item02 that opens after click on that button of DetailPage, one ModalPage03.html for item03 that opens after click on… and so on… ;)

The ModalPage is equal (the same) to the MoreDetailsPage I was talking about above.

---

### Summary

Again: The content of every single ModalPage.html/MoreDetailsPage.html is totally unique and needs to be hard coded.

I will create five pages (ModalPage01.html, ModalPage02.html, ModalPage03.html, ModalPage04.html, ModalPage05.html), which are the MoreDetailsPage pages that contain individual content after you clicked the button that appears on DetailPage after you clicked item01, item02, item03, item04 or item05.

*Would look like this:*

- list.html — item01 — (click)="goToDetailPage(detail)" >>> detail.html —  (click)="openModal()" >>> modalpage01.html
- list.html — item02 — (click)="goToDetailPage(detail)" >>> detail.html —  (click)="openModal()" >>> modalpage02.html
- list.html — item03 — (click)="goToDetailPage(detail)" >>> detail.html —  (click)="openModal()" >>> modalpage03.html
- list.html — item04 — (click)="goToDetailPage(detail)" >>> detail.html –  (click)="openModal()" >>> modalpage04.html
- list.html — item05 — (click)="goToDetailPage(detail)" >>> detail.html —  (click)="openModal()" >>> modalpage05.html

**In words:**

- On list.html click on item01 opens detail.html, click on button opens modalpage01.html.
- On list.html click on item02 opens detail.html, click on button opens modalpage02.html.
- and so on…

---

[Here is a graphic I made to more visualize my vision.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IyFj4.jpg)

Comment: Hey, can you share your code so far so that it was easier to help you?

Comment: So the challenge you have is that MoreDetailsPage0X needs to get some data from the DetailsPage and such data is interpolated / not really available?

Comment: Hi Sergey, **wow** – it means the world to me, that you’re answering me! Really! I mean, it’s my first time here on StackOverflow and I really appreciate your will to support me. I’ve added all the requested code for you and I really hope that helps you understanding my problem, as it is not the challenge you wrote about in your last comment. Now I’m pretty excited for your response. :) Greetings from Germany! (BTW: I hope my English is not that bad and you understand everything I’m writing down here… ;) @SergeyRudenko

Comment: This is now a good level of detail;) I will take a look in an hour or so. BTW your English is great, do not worry about it.

Comment: last thing - can you share the structure of your json file? if you can't share actual content - just share "data shape" with some dummy data if popssible

Comment: Thank you so much @SergeyRudenko ! There’s no problem sharing the .json file with you as all the code above is replaced with placeholders. Actually I don’t think that the data file will help you, cause everything is ok with the code and it works fine. But hey, I’m not the expert. I will provide you with the code in about half an hour. :)

Comment: Cool, now the picture is clearer so its Page => Detail => MoreDetail and the latter part is the one you want to be also not "hardcoded". But then question - what is the content that you want there if its not json? where it will come from any example?

Comment: So the reason I am asking this is because you will still want to have data source that will populate such "MoreDetailsPage" modal template and based on where that data is right now there is a solution. So the last bit you need to share is what is that data you want to show in the more detail modal. Makes sense?

Comment: At the end I will need to access every single MoreDetailsPage within the file structure to edit the unique content of every MoreDetailsPage. For example, there are some MoreDetailsPage pages which should only use an iframe. Others will be filled with video content, others with some images, a few with text only. I just need the freedom to fill the content individually in a hardcoding way, not through a .json file.

Comment: The DetailPage is fine getting its content via .json, cause this is a comfortable way. But I don’t need this for the MoreDetailsPage. — I just want to generate some pages via ionic g page MoreDetailsPage01 and want that button on the DetailsPage to direct to these pages, but MoreDetailsPage01 for item01, MoreDetailsPage02 for item02 et cetera… @SergeyRudenko Maybe I need to provide my vision in a more visual way. I think I’m going to create an animated gif or a graphic that points out what I’m looking for. I totally understand that’s a bit curious. :)

Comment: But again, I'm so thankfully for your time and help. @SergeyRudenko here in Germany it’s close to 11pm and I have to get up early tomorrow. I will come back to you tomorrow. Have a nice day. Thanks a ton!

Comment: I see - ok so yes visual UX would help. !

Comment: @SergeyRudenko I’ve added a graphic to point my vision. Really hope that helps as I’m slowly feeling kind of desperate how to describe even more what I’m looking for to achieve (and maybe it’s something that is not realizable). ;)

Comment: @ROP I have only one question, you want to generate a new page on runtime?

Comment: @DiegoCardozo thank you so much for your interest in my question! :) Well, I’m pretty sorry, but what means on runtime? Do you mean that the pages will be created when the app is running and somebody clicks on that button? If so: No, the MoreDetailsPage01–05 will be added before simply by using ionic g page MoreDetailsPage0x… (So the file structure on the picture I’ve added to my question is the starting point.) — Sorry, if I’m not getting it. :)

Comment: Note: Whenever I’m adding another item to the list (which I’m doing through the .json), I would have to add a new MoreDetailsPage manually, but that’s exactly what I want. It’s only how to make it possible to let the button on the DetailPage know which MoreDetailsPage (01–05) it should open after click. ;)

Comment: Awesome, I'll craft my answer, I wanted to check that before just to answer the right question.

Comment: @DiegoCardozo No, you’re awesome! ;) Pretty excited now… :)

Comment: Hi @SergeyRudenko – hope you’re fine! Are you still interested in helping me with the described issues? I’m not hustling you, so please don’t misunderstand this. I’m just asking as your last response is about six days ago. If your not interested anymore, please let me know. That would be great. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `@IonicPage()` decorator to handle this case.

If you run `ionic g page MyModal01` that will create a component with the `@IonicPage()` decorator.

So then you can do something like this to your button in your details page template:

```
<button ion-button [navPush]="getShowMorePage(detail)">Open Project</button>
```

And this in your details page .ts:

```
getShowMorePage(detail: any): string {
   return `MyModal0${detail.id}Page`; // Just as an example I used the Id.
}
```

That will load the MyModal0XPage, just remember that you must create a page not a component with the ionic cli and don't remove the `@IonicPage()` decorator.

Here you have a link to stackblitz:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-t6sas6

Export the project, change the main.ts file and put this inside:

```
import { platformBrowserDynamic } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule);
```

Also update the package.json in this section:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@ionic/app-scripts": "3.1.8",
    "ionic": "3.20.0",
    "typescript": "2.3.4"
  }
```

Then run `ionic serve` in the folder of the project.

You usually don't need to do that in a stackblitz project, this is just because the DeepLink of Ionic was not working in the web.

Comment: Really appreciate your effort! Well, unfortunately I’ve made a mistake by creating that graphic attached to my question. The files I’ve created for MoreDetailsPage0x (01–05) have the `@IonicPage()` decorator as I simply created them by running `ionic g page MoreDetailsPage0x`. (The whole code above shows only placeholders. For the graphic I just renamed some files that I duplicated to get that file structure screenshot, but I made a mistake and the `moredetails0x.module.ts` files we’re missing.) But these module.ts files are part of my file structure of course.

Comment: For the details page .ts part: Wouldn’t it be possible to create something like > if item01 was clicked, open MyModalPage01 after clicking that button, else if item02 was clicked, open MyModalPage02 after clicking that button, else if item03 was clicked, open MyModalPage03 after clicking that button et cetera? :)

Comment: BTW: I’ve updated and replaced the graphic attached to my question to make it clear, that the MoreDetailsPage pages actually use the `@IonicPage` decorator. ;)

Comment: Well, you can do that, using the string reference to the page you will be able to load the module for the MyModalPage0X that you will use and not all the Modules, that will save you a lot of MBs in your main js bundle. In the other hand you can create an if statement for each modal but to do that you must have a reference to each modal component and that is expensive if you want to keep the app lightweight and fast.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the explanation! This sounds like what I am looking for, but I don’t have enough knowledge to code something like this. Even though my question was full of code (and it may look like I’m a pro), I only know how to handle things that are already there – if you know what I mean. ;) I’m almost perfect with HTML and CSS, but that’s it. Everything else I’m just experimenting with. Although I’m good in trying to understand things, this is beyond my skills. But I also don’t wanna take more of your time (as you already tried to help me) and ask you to code this > bad conscience… :/

Comment: Don't worry, let me see if I can create a small project in stackblitz

Comment: That would be absolutely fantastic! Really appreciate that!

Comment: Hi @DiegoCardozo – everything’s fine? Hope you’re feeling good. Are you still interested in helping me with the code? I’m not hustling you, so please don’t get it wrong. Take your time! I just wanna make sure, that I’m not waiting for nothing. ;) Take care, Rob

Comment: @ROP sorry about that, I have added a link to a demo, you have to follow the steps of the answer, remember to check this answer as the solution if this works for you, take care.

Comment: Please don’t excuse yourself – I’ve got time and really appreciate the fact that somebody who don’t know me wants to help me. I know, this is what StackOverflow is for, but however I’m overwhelmed that you sacrifice your spare time for helping me. Well, thank you so so much for the extended answer and the Stackblitz! I’ve tested it and this totally is what I was looking for! But there are still two things I’m having problems with. Maybe just because I’m a newbie…

Comment: First: I’m getting the following error `Runtime Error
undefined is not an object (evaluating 'detail.id)` — I know, you commented out that this is just some kind of example, but what to do to not get that error message?

Comment: Second: Correct me if I’m wrong, but your home.ts is my list.ts file (see code above as part of the question), right? My list.ts file is responsible for generating the items list on the main page, using the .json-file. In your example you’re using another way to generate those list items `populateItems(): void {
    this.items.push({ id: 1, title: 'First item', description: 'Random stuff'});
    this.items.push({ id: 2, title: 'Second item', description: 'Random stuff'});
    this.items.push({ id: 3, title: 'Third item', description: 'Random stuff'});
  }`.

Comment: Exactly, in your case your list will use another field instead of the id you can use the index of the item in the ngFor or something like that, the result will be the same. you can change this line in your html -> [navParams]="getNavParamItem(item)" and instead put something like [navParams]="getNavParamItem(index)", the ngFor directive will provide you with that index. Your detail doesn't have an id prop, that is the issue.

Comment: Is there any chance to find a way of combining both? I mean, I would love to use my list.ts file code in combination with what you’ve done to achieve what I was looking for. I thought I could implement everything myself using parts of your solution, but yours works due to the fact that the myModal0x pages open with reference to home.ts, right? I mean, there’s some dependance between home.ts and item-details.ts? I really hope you know what I’m talking about… :D

Comment: Well you don't have a dependency, that is the nice part of this. You can use the whole object, the `Topic` object, and use the Id of that one, that will solve your problem, then when you want to show the details just get the properties of `topic.detail.timeStart` (as an example). The HomePage of my example is the ListPage of your current app, the idea is the same, it will hold a list of topics (items in my case).

Comment: Check the item-details.module.ts file, If you do the same for your details page and from your ListPage you call the DetailsPage in the same way that I did it, you will end with the same solution.

Comment: @DiegoCardozo Finaly I have marked your answer as accepted and the question should be solved now. I’m feeling so sorry for the late reply, but I was sick for a long time and two friends died meanwhile. That’s why I focused on other things rather than some coding skills. Anyway, I really appreciate your effort and the time you’ve spent for helping me. Thank you so much Diego!!! All my best and take care. :)